# TypeError with 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a `test` folder
the structure within the folder

```
__init.py__
aa.py
test.py
```

for `aa.py`

```
class aa:
    def __init__(self,max):
        self.max=max
        print max+1

    def hello(self):
        print(max)
```

for `test.py`

```
import aa
abc = aa(100)
abc.hello()
```

when run `test.py`, I have an error

```
    abc = aa(100)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

What is the problem?

Comment: `from aa import aa` (now `aa` is the class `aa`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a module `aa`, and in that module you have a class `aa`. You only import the module.

Either do:

```
import aa
abc = aa.aa(100)
```

or:

```
from aa import aa
abc = aa(100)
```

or, even better, use separate names for module and class.

Comment: it works! but where did I create a module aa, isn't I only create a class?

Comment: I don't understand that comment. Your module is the file "aa.py", which contains a class. Python is not Java.

Answer (score 0):

you need to do like this.

```
from aa import aa
abc = aa(100)
abc.hello()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `from aa import *` instead of `import aa` in your `test.py` script.