# Calling class in another folder

Tags: python, python-2.7

Given the folder structure as follows:

```
folder1
  __init.py__
  python1.py
folder2
  __init.py__
  class1.py
```

say in `class1.py` I have

```
class aa:
  def __init__(self,max):
    self.max=max

  def hello(self):
    print(self.max)
```

What should I import from `python1.py` to invoke `aa.hello()`?

i.e., in `python1.py`

```
#what do I need to import here

myaa=aa(100)
myaa.hello()
```

Comment: What should you import *from where*? From a script external to the folder structure or from one of them? Also, `hello` is probably incorrectly indented. And you wouldn't call `aa.hello()`, you would create an instance of `aa` and the call its `hello` method.

Comment: Have you looked at https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html?

Comment: How is this different from [the question I just answered for you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26337201/typeerror-with-module-object-is-not-callable)?

Comment: @javidcf question edited, it's from python1.py

Comment: @DanielRoseman question edited, different folder structures

Comment: @jonrsharpe This two folders are immediate folders under a pycharm project, from python1 import aa does not work

Comment: Then would you please **edit the question** to include that detail, what exactly you've tried and what precisely *"does not work"* means (e.g. full error traceback)? And, again, have you read the docs?

Comment: I got it works it's from folder1.class1 import aa

Comment: @jonrsharpe side track a bit, how do you format your text under the comments? (e.g., how do you bold **"edit the question"**, and format your codes)

Comment: Same as in a question - `backticks (\`) for code`, **two asterisks (\*\*) for bold**, *one asterisk (\*) for italic*

Answer (score 0):

Answer my own:

```
from folder2.class1 import aa
```

Comment: This will only work if the parent folder is in the PYTHONPATH/PATH. In general how are you gong to distribute this code? You really want to carefully read the Python module docs and think about how you will use or distribute this code in the future.